# In the context of Bell nonlocality, is the space of behaviours a hypersphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality

I am currently reading Bell Nonlocality review paper by Brunner et al. (2014). On page 424,

> A behaviour can be viewed as a point $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{\Delta^2 m^2}$ belonging to the probability space $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathbb{R}^{\Delta^2 m^2}$ defined by the positivity constraints $p(ab|xy) \geq 0$ and the normalization constraints $\sum_{a,b=1}^{\Delta} p(ab|xy) = 1$. Due to the normalization constraints $\mathcal{P}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\Delta^2 m^2}$ of dimension $\dim \mathcal{P} = (\Delta^2 - 1)m^2$.

Does that actually mean the probability space is a $(\Delta^2-1)m^2$-sphere?

Comment: each post should focus on a single aspect. You can ask separate questions on separate posts. Here, I'd edit the post to focus it on one of the two questions, to avoid it being too broad. Also, what makes you think $\mathcal P$ should be a hypersphere here?

Comment: Ah, sorry for posting two questions since this is my first time asking in stack exchange. According to my understanding, since $\mathbf{p}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{\Delta^2 m^2}$ and the normalization condition, $|| {\mathbf{p}}|| = 1$. Am I wrong in my understanding? Is it actually just a hyperplane?

Comment: no worries, should get reopened soon. Normalisation condition for probabilities is that the sum of elements is 1 though, not the sum of the squares. A sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has normalisation $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$. Probabilities satisfy $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$, and thus form a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), not a sphere

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a little bit:

1. In general, a (finite-dimensional) "probability space" is a set of positive reals $p_i\ge0$ such that $\sum_i p_i=1$. This is generally called a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), and you can imagine it as a section of a hyperplane passing through the basis vectors $\mathbf e_i$.
2. It's worth noting that technically speaking the space of behaviour is not the same thing as the space of probability distributions, because some of the indices, here $x,y$, are not bound by normalisation condition like the others. The defining constraints are precisely as you wrote. Geometrically, each linear constraint $\sum_{a,b} p(ab|xy)=1$ defines a hyperplane. Imagine that, for every choice of $x,y$, you get a probability space on the remaining two variables $a,b$. You have one such constraint for each $x,y$, thus the space of behaviours is bound to be in the intersection of all the associated hyperplanes. There are $m^2$ such linear constraints, and without the constraint the space would be $\mathbb{R}^{\Delta^2 m^2}$, hence the dimension once the constraints are taken into account is $\Delta^2 m^2-m^2$.
3. This is not a sphere. A (hyper)sphere is characterised by a quadratic constraint of the form $\sum_i x_i^2=1$.

Comment: Well, it *is* a sphere (or can be one, depending on the basis vectors -- I haven't thought through the general case) in a different norm. (Well, almost -- the norm does not ensure positivity of the coefficient -- but up to that, $\sum p_i=1$ is just $\|p\|_1=1$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch fair enough. I meant "sphere in the standard Euclidean metric", which is what I guess OP meant.

Comment: I agree, that's probably what the OP meant. Just felt is is worth recalling that not all spheres are round ;)